# Parabolic Bruhat graphs for exceptional types

Tags: algebraic-groups, computer-algebra, exceptional-groups, kazhdan-lusztig, bruhat-order

I am looking for some computer software or a reference for some parabolic Bruhat graphs.  In particular, what I *really* need $E_8 \setminus E_7$.  Does anyone know where or how I'd find this?

Comment: Not helpful for your question, but looking at https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/categories/sage/categories/coxeter_groups.html, it appears that Sage has code for normal (not parabolic) Bruhat graphs.